getLastRow() in Apps Script returns error: "This operation is not allowed on cells in typed columns."
I have a simple sheet with 30 rows and 8 columns and getLastRow() returns this strange error:

"This operation is not allowed on cells in typed columns."

My code below is a function that syncs two sheets.
Compared to the studentsheet, the importsheet has one new row and a deleted row.
When I run the code the new student is correctly added to the studentsheet using the first for loop.
Then the code wants to continue with deleting the deleted row.
But before I could do anything the line
importrows = importSheet.getLastRow(); 

Generates the error:

"This operation is not allowed on cells in typed columns."

In the first lines of the code I'm using the same line of  code without a problem:
function sync() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var importSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Import Students');
  var studentSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Students');
  var cell = importSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  if (cell == "") {
    ui.alert("No data to synchronize."); // maybe importrange has not loaded the data yet
    return;
  }
  var importrows = importSheet.getLastRow();
  var studentrows = studentSheet.getLastRow();
  var importRange = importSheet.getRange(2, 4, importrows - 1, 2); // range of all names and telnrs of import data
  var studentRange = studentSheet.getRange(2, 4, studentrows - 1, 2); // range of  all names and telnrs of student data
  var copyRange;
  var import_data = importRange.getValues();
  var student_data = studentRange.getValues();
  var searchnr;
  var laststudentrow;
  var maxstudentrow;
  var found_row;
  var i;
  var stepcell;
  var validList = [];
  var cursus;
  var rule;
  var newstudents = 0;
  var deletedstudents = 0;
  var updatedstudents = 0;
  var rowchanged = false;
  var coursechanged = false;
  var importrowRange;
  var studentrowRange;
  var importrow = [];
  var studentrow = [];

  var cur_date = new Date();
  var cur_date_str = Utilities.formatDate(cur_date, "GMT+1", "dd-MM-yyyy")

  //check and add new students

  for (i = 0; i < importrows - 1; i++) {
    searchnr = import_data[i][1];
    found_row = array_search(student_data, searchnr, 2);
    if (found_row == -1) { // new row found
      // add row to students sheet
      copyRange = importSheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 8);
      laststudentrow = studentSheet.getLastRow();
      maxstudentrow = studentSheet.getMaxRows();
      if (laststudentrow == maxstudentrow) {
        studentSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxstudentrow, 1); // add 1 row to sheet
      }
      copyRange.copyTo(studentSheet.getRange(laststudentrow + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      newstudents = newstudents + 1;
      stepcell = studentSheet.getRange(laststudentrow + 1, 8); // cell met Step;
      cursus = studentSheet.getRange(laststudentrow + 1, 7).getValue();
      validList = getValidRangeForCourse(cursus);
      if (validList.length > 0) {
        rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(validList, true).build();
        stepcell.setDataValidation(rule);
      } else {
        stepcell.clearDataValidations();
      }
    }
  }

  //check and add delete students, that are not longer in the registration
  //check and update existing students

  //importrows = importSheet.getLastRow();  
  studentrows = studentSheet.getLastRow();
  importRange = importSheet.getRange(2, 1, importrows - 1, 7); // range of all names and telnrs of import data
  studentRange = studentSheet.getRange(2, 1, studentrows - 1, 7); // range of  all names and telnrs of student data
  import_data = [];
  student_data = [];
  import_data = importRange.getValues();
  student_data = studentRange.getValues();

  for (i = studentrows - 1; i > 0; i--) { // check rows from bottom to top
    searchnr = student_data[i - 1][4];
    found_row = array_search(import_data, searchnr, 5);
    if (found_row == -1) { // student not found
      // delete student from students sheet
      studentSheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
      deletedstudents = deletedstudents + 1;
    }
    else {
      // check if existing student data has changed
      rowchanged = false;
      coursechanged = false;
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (student_data[i - 1][j] != import_data[found_row][j]) {
          rowchanged = true;
          if (j == 6) coursechanged = true;
        }
      }
      if (rowchanged) {
        importrowRange = importSheet.getRange(found_row + 2, 1, 1, 8);
        importrow = importrowRange.getValues();
        studentrowRange = studentSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 8);
        studentrowRange.setValues(importrow);
        updatedstudents = updatedstudents + 1;
      }
      if (coursechanged) { // wijzig stepvalidatie
        stepcell = studentSheet.getRange(i + 1, 8); // cell met Step;
        cursus = import_data[found_row][6];
        validList = getValidRangeForCourse(cursus);
        if (validList.length > 0) {
          rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(validList, true).build();
          stepcell.setDataValidation(rule);
        } else {
          stepcell.clearDataValidations();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ui.alert("Result of synchronization:\nNew students = " + newstudents + "\nUpdated students = " + updatedstudents + "\nDeleted students = " + deletedstudents);
}

Could someone help me?

Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a minimal, reproducible example.

An MRE is not optional. Please provide sample data and examples of expected outcomes.

Also show the exact error message you see in My Executions, complete with line numbers and call stack. Don't paraphrase but show the complete error.

1) importrows = importSheet.getLastRow(); which line is generating the error? Line#11 or line#70. 2) AAMOI, what is the purpose of line #70 since no rows have been added or deleted to "importsheet". 3) Where is the rest of the code? Would you please supply the entire script.

I replaced the code with the full code.
I also commented the line "importrows = importSheet.getLastRow();"
When I run the script I get the same error on the next line:
studentrows = studentSheet.get
The full error text in Executions is: 1:04:38 PM
Error, Exception: This operation is not allowed on cells in typed columns.
sync,

The error text is followed by the line number of the code and that line is:
studentrows = studentrows = studentSheet.getLastRow();

I will try to add some sample data later today.

Do you have tables?

Show the exact error message you see in My Executions, complete with line numbers and call stack. Don't paraphrase but show the complete error.


importrows = importSheet.getLastRow();
"This operation is not allowed on cells in typed columns."

The error you quote doesn't sound like what you'd get from the trying to access the Sheet.getLastRow() method. It is possible that the error is caused by another operation and thrown later when a cache is flushed.
Remove any tables and merged cells you have in the spreadsheet and see if the code works then.

The idea to remove the table was a very good idea.
I used "Revert to unformatted data" in the Students sheet and the problem is gone.
This is not the first problem I had with a table.
Maybe tables are new in sheets and not bug free?
It's still strange that I got the error when I used the import sheet that doesn't contain a table, but maybe you are right when you write "t is possible that the error is caused by another operation and thrown later when a cache is flushed."
Thanks a lot for your great help.
It think for the time being I will not use tables.

If you are using array functions please know that they interfer with the calculation of getLastRow() or atleast they did in the past.

@doubleunary ... Just trying to help.  Don't take it so personally.

It's been a problem for a long time I don't know if it's resolved or not because I hardly ever use cell formulas.

@Cooper oh you mean array formulas. They'll indeed cause the data range to expand, but only if they fill tailing cells with "" or some such value. To avoid the issue, fill tailing cells with nulls by using iferror(ø) instead of "".

I did mean array formula.  I guess my lack of use of formula shows.
